# Use parameters from additional configs in dvc 2.0

Tags: python, dvc

Using dvc version 2.0.18 and python 3.9.2 I want to use parameters defined in a config file different from params.yaml when configuring the parameters of the stages in `dvc.yaml`. However, it does not work as I expected.

MWE:
Git repo + dvc init:

```
.
├── dvc.yaml
├── preproc.yaml
└── test.py
```

dvc.yaml:

```
vars:
  - preproc.yaml
stages:
  test:
    cmd: python test.py
    deps:
      - test.py
    params:
      - important_parameter
```

preproc.yaml:

```
important_parameter: 123
```

Running `dvc repro` lead to the following error:

```
ERROR: failed to reproduce 'dvc.yaml': dependency 'params.yaml' does not exist
```

Creating a dummy params.yaml without content gives:

```
WARNING: 'params.yaml' is empty.
ERROR: failed to reproduce 'dvc.yaml': Parameters 'important_parameter' are missing from 'params.yaml'.
```

What am I missing? Is this possible at all with the templating feature?

Comment: What's "MWE"? :)

Comment: The quick answer is to put the param name in a substitution expression i.e. `${important_parameter}` but @shcheklein's answer below is more correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you don't need the templating feature in this case. As shown in this [example](https://dvc.org/doc/command-reference/params#examples-python-parameters-file):

```yaml
stages:
  train:
    cmd: python train.py
    deps:
      - users.csv
    params:
      - params.py:
          - BOOL
          - INT
          - TrainConfig.EPOCHS
          - TrainConfig.layers
    outs:
      - model.pkl
```

The way to redefine the default `params.yaml` is to specify the file name explicitly in the `params:` section:

```yaml
params:
  - preproc.yaml:
    - important_parameter
```

Also, when you create a stage either with [`dvc run`](https://dvc.org/doc/command-reference/run) (not recommended) or [`dvc stage add`](https://dvc.org/doc/command-reference/stage/add), you can provide the params file name explicitly as a prefix:

```sh
dvc run -n train -d train.py -d logs/ -o users.csv -f \
          -p parse_params.yaml:threshold,classes_num \
          python train.py
```

Here ^^ `parse_params.yaml` is a custom params file.

Please, let me know if it solves the problem and if you have any other questions :)

Comment: Thanks that solves the initial question. The link you included explain this perfectly well. Still we might benefit from refining the documentation. In [link](https://dvc.org/doc/user-guide/project-structure/pipelines-files) it says "To load additional params files, list them in the top vars, in the desired order, e.g.:". This is where my initial confusion originated from.